# In search of opinions on web based version control systems

Tags: php, svn, version-control, document

Researching various open source, web-based document management/version control systems. I've checked google/questions here, etc...

I'm looking for a lightweight web-based (apache) document mgmt/version control app that runs on top of SVN.

I need to have the ability to:

- have multiple users checkin/checkout
- have a workflow (when userA checks the file in, and finishes the app passes it to the next person, etc...
- the app needs to allow me to have a structure where the files can be moved as a group. the files will be changed on a monthly basis
- app needs to have a access/premission control system. some people can see certain files, and perform certain actions on the files

I imagine that I'm going to have 40-50 people dealing with the different files. I imagine that I'm going to have 2000-3000 files that have to be massaged.

I'd prefer that the app be php based if possible, as opposed to a straight java app.

Thanks

Comment: If any of these answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Subversion:

WikiPedia: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29)
Mainpage: [http://subversion.apache.org](http://subversion.apache.org/).

I honestly don't know if it fits all requirements that you've posted, as I've only used it on projects involving small teams, but you should be able to sort that out by reading the WikiPedia page linked above. That said, it definitely meets the web-dev version control.

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla installation of SVN isn't going to do this; it only does regular version control (commits, branches, etc.). There are plenty of [web based svn interfaces](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=svn+web+interface&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but all they do is give you a way to work with regular svn over the web. The document management features and workflow you require are going to come from some other document management system; I don't know of any that use svn as a back end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) provides a web-based interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

For a simplistic, but working version control system made entirely in PHP, built on top of ASVCS, take a look at IntraVersion (http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Development-Scripts-js/IntraVersion-39805.html) Not much, but for those stuck like me with no server to host private projects on at the moment, it's a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [knowledge tree](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Community). PHP, open source, with support/hosting available. I've used it in the past. It sucks less than other solutions.